# Magento 2 and Animated GIFs as Product Images

Tags: magento2, product-images, image

Is there a way in Magento 2 to allow for animated gifs as product images?

I can upload them to the backend without any issues, but when I view a product on the front-end it just shows them as separate images.

Comment: Where do you use the GIF? In a CMS page? That should work.  
 Why don't you consider jQuery instead of a GIF?

Comment: No not in the CMS page. In the product detail pages as product images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While allowing it may be possible in one or another way, it only creates new edgecases which need to get handled.
One example are thumbnails, the other resize.

Also you (for size reasons) probably only want the gif to be shown on the product page, not the category pages.

My suggestion is to create a complete new attribute and do the rest on the frontend template.

Another possible way would be to see if there is already some feature, which allows for video uploads to products. There a gif support would make sense because auf the similar use and requirements videos have(size, only start loading on click)

Comment: Thanks we decided to do the video as a work around. We could convert the gifs to mp4s and then upload them to youtube. Not the most elegant solution, but it works. I wish Magento allowed for animated gifs as you could create 360 views on the image without having to have another plugin to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We released an extension for this recently. This adds support for GIF images in Magento 2 platform.

The extension can be found at URL: https://redchamps.com/product-animated-gif-images-magento-2-extension.html

**Please note that this is a paid extension and it is developed by RedChamps and I am the founder of that.**

Comment: Is this trustable module? Or any other options?

Comment: Yes, it works well. Unfortunately, not aware of any other option.

Comment: For what it's worth, we use this extension on https://www.xchair.com/buildx1.html#205=23&331=934 and it works well for us.