# Magento 2 GIF Animation is not working on frontend -- no solutions for previous questions

Tags: magento2, product-images, csv

**I am trying to upload .gif image for few products , image is uploading from csv  successfully**

**and animation also working in admin panel.**

***But issue here is when i am checking this product on frontend - image is displayed but Animation is not working on frontend***

But unable to find any solution.

please help me out on this.

Thanks...............

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code :

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image" type="ProductAjax\Animation\Model\Image" />
</config>
```

**image.php - overrided function setBaseFile.**

```
public function setBaseFile($file)
    {
        $this->_isBaseFilePlaceholder = false;

        if ($file && 0 !== strpos($file, '/', 0)) {
            $file = '/' . $file;
        }
        $baseDir = $this->_catalogProductMediaConfig->getBaseMediaPath();

        if ('/no_selection' == $file) {
            $file = null;
        }
        if ($file) {
            if (!$this->_fileExists($baseDir . $file) || !$this->_checkMemory($baseDir . $file)) {
                $file = null;
            }
        }
        if (!$file) {
            $this->_isBaseFilePlaceholder = true;
            // check if placeholder defined in config
            $isConfigPlaceholder = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                "catalog/placeholder/{$this->getDestinationSubdir()}_placeholder",
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
            $configPlaceholder = '/placeholder/' . $isConfigPlaceholder;
            if (!empty($isConfigPlaceholder) && $this->_fileExists($baseDir . $configPlaceholder)) {
                $file = $configPlaceholder;
            } else {
                $this->_newFile = true;
                return $this;
            }
        }

        $baseFile = $baseDir . $file;

        if (!$file || !$this->_mediaDirectory->isFile($baseFile)) {
            throw new \Exception(__('We can\'t find the image file.'));
        }

        $this->_baseFile = $baseFile;
        $test_extension = substr($file,strpos($file, ".") + 1); 
            if($test_extension == "gif" || $test_extension == "GIF")
            {
                $path [] = $this->_catalogProductMediaConfig->getBaseMediaPath();
            }
            else
            {
                // build new filename (most important params)
                $path = [
                    $this->_catalogProductMediaConfig->getBaseMediaPath(),
                    'cache',
                    $this->getDestinationSubdir(),
                ];
                if (!empty($this->_width) || !empty($this->_height)) {
                    $path[] = "{$this->_width}x{$this->_height}";
                }

                // add misk params as a hash
                $miscParams = [
                    ($this->_keepAspectRatio ? '' : 'non') . 'proportional',
                    ($this->_keepFrame ? '' : 'no') . 'frame',
                    ($this->_keepTransparency ? '' : 'no') . 'transparency',
                    ($this->_constrainOnly ? 'do' : 'not') . 'constrainonly',
                    $this->_rgbToString($this->_backgroundColor),
                    'angle' . $this->_angle,
                    'quality' . $this->_quality,
                ];

                // if has watermark add watermark params to hash
                if ($this->getWatermarkFile()) {
                    $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkFile();
                    $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkImageOpacity();
                    $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkPosition();
                    $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkWidth();
                    $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkHeight();
                }

                $path[] = md5(implode('_', $miscParams));
            }
        // append prepared filename
        $this->_newFile = implode('/', $path) . $file;
        // the $file contains heading slash

        return $this;
    }
```

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190039/72911)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for comment , ...
can you elaborate please i cant understand as module view

Comment: removed that md5 encryption code and call image path directly.

Comment: i have tried , as you said but total detail  messedup................pls help me out on this please

Comment: simple code this code for override function "setBaseFile()" in image.php file using preference and preference define in di.xml file

Comment: please check above code what i did  once , if any wrong please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I have done as below please let me know any changes

Step:1 ---  ProductAjax/Animation/etc/module.xml

Step:2 ---  ProductAjax/Animation/etc/di.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0"?>    
         <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image" type="ProductAjax\Animation\Model\Image" />
     </config>
```

Step:3 --- ProductAjax/Animation/Model/Product/Image.php

```
     <?php

   namespace ProductAjax\Animation\Model\Product;

   public function setBaseFile($file)
     {
    $this->_isBaseFilePlaceholder = false;

    if ($file && 0 !== strpos($file, '/', 0)) {
        $file = '/' . $file;
    }
    $baseDir = $this->_catalogProductMediaConfig->getBaseMediaPath();

    if ('/no_selection' == $file) {
        $file = null;
    }
    if ($file) {
        if (!$this->_fileExists($baseDir . $file) || !$this->_checkMemory($baseDir . $file)) {
            $file = null;
        }
    }
    if (!$file) {
        $this->_isBaseFilePlaceholder = true;
        // check if placeholder defined in config
        $isConfigPlaceholder = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            "catalog/placeholder/{$this->getDestinationSubdir()}_placeholder",
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        $configPlaceholder = '/placeholder/' . $isConfigPlaceholder;
        if (!empty($isConfigPlaceholder) && $this->_fileExists($baseDir . $configPlaceholder)) {
            $file = $configPlaceholder;
        } else {
            $this->_newFile = true;
            return $this;
        }
    }

    $baseFile = $baseDir . $file;

    if (!$file || !$this->_mediaDirectory->isFile($baseFile)) {
        throw new \Exception(__('We can\'t find the image file.'));
    }

    $this->_baseFile = $baseFile;
    $test_extension = substr($file,strpos($file, ".") + 1); 
        if($test_extension == "gif" || $test_extension == "GIF")
        {
            $path [] = $this->_catalogProductMediaConfig->getBaseMediaPath();
        }
        else
        {
            // build new filename (most important params)
            $path = [
                $this->_catalogProductMediaConfig->getBaseMediaPath(),
                'cache',
                $this->getDestinationSubdir(),
            ];
            if (!empty($this->_width) || !empty($this->_height)) {
                $path[] = "{$this->_width}x{$this->_height}";
            }

            // add misk params as a hash
            $miscParams = [
                ($this->_keepAspectRatio ? '' : 'non') . 'proportional',
                ($this->_keepFrame ? '' : 'no') . 'frame',
                ($this->_keepTransparency ? '' : 'no') . 'transparency',
                ($this->_constrainOnly ? 'do' : 'not') . 'constrainonly',
                $this->_rgbToString($this->_backgroundColor),
                'angle' . $this->_angle,
                'quality' . $this->_quality,
            ];

            // if has watermark add watermark params to hash
            if ($this->getWatermarkFile()) {
                $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkFile();
                $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkImageOpacity();
                $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkPosition();
                $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkWidth();
                $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkHeight();
            }

            $path[] = md5(implode('_', $miscParams));
        }
    // append prepared filename
    $this->_newFile = implode('/', $path) . $file;
    // the $file contains heading slash

    return $this;
}
```

please let me know any change i need to do