# Magento-2.2.5 GIF Images uploaded for product not working in frontend

Tags: product-images, magento-2.2.5, image-upload, gif

I am trying to upload .gif image in backend in magento2.2.5 for downloadable product but it is not displaying properly in frontend.

> **product image save in below path:** catalog/product\cache\960x720//e/z/video-to-gif_1.gif

Image is displayed but animation is not working.Also refer to [Magento 2 - GIF Images , Animation is not working on frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189888/magento-2-gif-images-animation-is-not-working-on-frontend) but not working

Screenshot of admin and frontend:
http://prntscr.com/r4k69p
http://prntscr.com/r4k6vw

Comment: attach screenshot

Comment: In Mage 1 animated gifs was not support natively due to using GD2 as the image processor. Which I assume will be the same in Magento 2. What we did in Mage1 was extended the Image validator function and passed gif images to Imagecraft instead. I will look at finding time to draft an example later if no one else provides a solution