# Transposed images (white with black background)

Tags: product-images

My developer is in the middle of upgrading my site from M1 to M2 2.3.2. Some of the product images that should have a white back ground now have a black background. My developer says it's because M2 does not support .gif images. Does anyone have an answer how to get around this without having to manually change each image? [image]

Update: We have an answer if anyone else has experienced this problem. Answer: "Magento 2 was compressing .gif files and making them look like this. We have disabled the compress option for .gif files and they are fine now."

Comment: Check this post if it helps! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189888/magento-2-gif-images-animation-is-not-working-on-frontend

Answer (score 0):

file:
vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php
change line ~79:
from:

```
if (in_array($fileType, [IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_GIF])) {
```

to:

```
if (in_array($fileType, [IMAGETYPE_PNG])) {
```